# Create a unique id with built-in checksum?

Tags: c#, unique, checksum

I want to auto-generate a unique 8-10 character ID string that includes a checksum bit of some kind to guard against a typo at data entry.  I would prefer something that does not have sequential numbers where the data entry person would end up in a "rut" and get used to typing the same sequence all the time.

Are there any best practices/ pitfalls associated with this sort of thing?

**UPDATE:** OK, I guess I need to provide more detail.

1. I want to use alphanumerics, not just digits
2. I want behavior similar to a credit card checksum, except with 8-10 characters instead of 16 digits
3. I want to have the id be unique; there should not be a possibility of collision.

**SECOND UPDATE** OK, I don't understand what is confusing about this, but I will try to explain further.  I am trying to create tracking numbers that will go on forms, which will be filled out and data-entered at a later time.  I will generate the id and slap it on the form; the id needs to be unique, it needs to support a LOT of numbers, and it needs to be reasonably idiot-proof for data-entry.

I don't know if this has been done, or even if it can be done, but it does not hurt to ask.

Comment: So, basically an ISBN, UPC, or EAN?

Comment: I am confused by your question. You say you want to auto-generate an ID string and yet you are concerned about typos during data entry. Is a user creating the ID string or is it automatic?

Comment: @ArashN `GUID` doesn't have a check digit.

Comment: @ArashN - GUIDs are rather longer than 8-10 characters.

Comment: Something along that line, yes.  The trick is the autogeneration of the unique values in an easily validatable manner.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs Just get a `Math.Rand()` value of appropriate length and then generate the check digit using any known algorithm. Some require a set length. Others don't. Old ISBN is exactly 9 digits, but uses `X` as the check digit if it's calculated to be `10`. Search around a bit.

Comment: @ScottSmith, the user would not be creating the id, but referencing it.  This is not a barcode, but rather a reference number.  I'm thinking like credit cards or upcs, but with a bit more control over the length and characters.

Comment: @Yuck, `Math.Rand()` has no reasonable means of offering uniqueness, and I want to do alphanumeric, possibly special characters as well.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs You've two separate problems then. (1) Generating a unique base value and (2) calculating a check-digit for that value.

Comment: @Yuck, that is the nature of the question I am asking.

Comment: What would be useful for us is a alpha reference number that not only contains a checksum but also parity so if 30% of the number is illegible then the rest can identify it still.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question is VERY general - thus just some general aspects:

- Does the ID need to be "unguessable" ?
  IF yes then some sort of hash should be in the mix.
- Does the ID need to be "secure" (like for example an activation key or something) ?
  IF yes then some sort of public key cryptography should be in the mix.
- Does the ID / checksum calculation need to be fast ?
  IF yes then perhaps some very simple algorithm like CRC32 or Luhn (credit card checksum algorithm) or soem barcode checksum algorithm could be worth looking at.
- Is the ID generation centralized ?
  IF not then you might need to check out GUIDs, current time, MAC address and similar stuff.

**UPDATE - as per comments:**

- use a sequence in the DB
- take that value and hash it, for example with MD5
- take the least significant 40-48 bits of that hash
- encode it as Base-36 (0-9 and A-Z) which gives you 8-10 "digits" (alphanumeric)
- check the result against the DB and discard if the ID already there (for the very rare possibility of a collision)
- calculate CRC-6-ITU (see http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-G.704-199810-I/en on page 3)
- attach the CRC result as the last "digit" (as base-36 too)
- and thus you have a unique ID including checksum

to check the entered value you can just recalculate CRC-6-ITU from all digits but the last one and compare the result with the last digit.

The above is rather "unguessable" but definitely not of "high security".

**UPDATE 2 - as per comment:**

For some inspiration on how to calculate CRC in javascript see [this](http://www.digsys.se/JavaScript/CRC.aspx) - it contains javascript code for CRC-8 etc.

You should be able to adapt this code based on the CRC-6-ITU polynomial.

Comment: in order of your questions, no, no, reasonably so, and yes.

Comment: the GUID is too large, the time is really too sequential, the MAC address... dunno how I would use that, but it's hex and 12 chars.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs thanks for the answers... will you store the generated IDs in a DB ? can you store an additional value in the DB which could be used to check the validity ?

Comment: yes, these id's will be stored in a database along with metadata related to the id.  (What the tracking id was assigned to, where it was sent, etc.)  I would prefer not to have to check against the db to ward against typo's, though... which is why I was looking into a relatively simple mechanism to support client-side validation.  Not perfect, but able to reduce the errors by a good margin.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs understood, please see my update for a step-by-step description.

Comment: if I hash the sequential id, it seems I am introducing the possibility of collision... while rare, it seems like it would eventually cause a problem if used enough.  Or does one of the other steps ensure uniqueness?

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs regarding the hash you are right - it is extremely unlikely but possible. to ensure 100% uniqueness you would check the generated ID against the DB to see if it has already been geenrated (updated my answer accordingly). OR are you generating the IDs client-side ?

Comment: I think this will work.  Now I just need to figure out how to validate the tracking id in the client (Javascript/ jQuery).  Thanks!

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs you are welcome... see my UPDATE 2 for a link/some hints on implementing CRC in javascript.

Answer (score 4):

You might imitate airline reservation systems: they convert a number into base-36, using A-Z and 0-9 as the characters. Their upper limit is thus 36^6.

If you need to *guarantee* uniqueness, and you don't want them to be sequential, you have to keep the used-up random numbers in a table somewhere.

After you have your random or pseudorandom ID, you only need to calculate your checkdigit.

[Use a CRC algorithm.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check) They can be adapted to any desired length (in your case, 6 bits).

**Edit**

In case it's not clear: even if you use alpha codes, you'll have to turn it into a number before generating the checkdigit.

**Edit**

1. Checksum validation is not heavyweight, it can be implemented client-side in javascript.
2. A six character alphanumeric (i.e. airline record locator) = 10 *octillion* numbers. Surely that's enough? (See [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=6%5E36) for exact result.)

Comment: (and I don't want to create my own checksum... I am definitely hoping a practice already exists for this)

Comment: +1 for indicating the need to save the used id's in a table if they can't be sequential jet have to be unique.

Comment: bleh... i was hoping for something a bit more elegant.  I'd really like the checksum validation to run client-side without a heavy library or centralized resources being consumed... but it does not sound like that is possible.

Comment: +! this is a good answer too, but a bit heavy on the database.

Comment: re Edit 2 above - its not 6^36 (10 octillion) but 36^6 = 2 billion 176 million 782 thousand 336

Answer (score 2):

Most credit cards use the [Luhn algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm) (also known as mod10 algorithm) as checksum algorithm to validate card numbers. From Wikipedia:

> The Luhn algorithm will detect any single-digit error, as well as
>   almost all transpositions of adjacent digits. It will not, however,
>   detect transposition of the two-digit sequence 09 to 90 (or vice
>   versa).

The algorithm is generic and can be applied to any identification number.

Comment: @L.B: See comments on the question - you would have to add the checksum digit to the generated id

Comment: Your answer includes only that minor part.

Answer (score 1):

As @BrokenGlass noted, you can use the Luhn check digit algorithm. Credit cards and the like use the Luhn algorithm *modulo* 10. *Luhn mod 10* is computes a check digit for a sentence drawn from the alphabet consisting solely of decimal digits (0-9). However, it is easily adapted to compute a check digit for sentences drawn from an alphabet of any size (binary, octal, hex, alphanumeric, etc.)

To do that, all you need are two methods and one property:

- **The number of codepoints in the alphabet in use.**

  This is essentially the *base* of the numbering system. For instance, the hexadecimal (base 16) alphabet consists of 16 characters (ignoring the issue of case-sensitivity): '0123456789ABCDEF'. '0'–'9' have their usual meaning; 'A'–'F' are the base-16 digits representing 10–15.
- **A means of converting a character from the alphabet in use into its corresponding codepoint.**

  For instance in hexadecimal, the characters '0'–'9' represent code points 0–9; the characters 'A'–'F' represent codepoints 10-15.
- **A means of converting a codepoint into the corresponding character.**

  The converse of the above. For instance, in hexadecimal, the codepoint 12 would convert to the character 'C'.

You should probably through an `ArgumentException`, if the code point given doesn't exist in the alphabet.

The Wikipedia article, ["Luhn mod N algorithm"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_mod_N_algorithm) does a pretty good job of explaining the computation of the check digit and its validation.